# Count elements in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

I am learning Django. I have a question about counting elements from tables.

```
class Opinion(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    books = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id.username + ' ' + self.book_id.title
```

My table Opinion is in relationship with built-in table User.
I am wondering how can I count how many opinions each user has added?

I would like to show information about users and the amount of opinions they have added on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.annotate(number_of_opinions=Count('opinion'))
```

The `User` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.number_of_opinions`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).